# Migrate to UEFI in Debian

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

Motherboard I had Debian installed on, is broken. I've installed another motherboard, but it only supports UEFI boot.

I have no UEFI partition, I don't know if I have GPT. I'm able to boot (from USB - it uses UEFI) with installer from Debian and mount disk to browse files.

As I understand, I need to:

- convert/make sure I use GPT
- resize root partition (I have no separate boot partition - everything is on /), to create partition for UEFI
- convert bootloader from old BIOS to UEFI boot schema

Can you give me some guidelines how to proceed?

Comment: I've not tried this myself, so I can't vouch for it, but as I understand it: You can install [`rEFInd` - an EFI bootloader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) on a USB thumb drive, boot from it, and then select your existing HDD with it. My experience is limited, but I think the issue may be that your old HDD has no EFI partition, therefore your new MoBo doesn't know what to do. But I think this is all very manufacturer-dependent (even though UEFI is a *standard*). [This blog](https://mmanoba.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/howto-install-refind-on-mac-machine-or-usb-stick-hard-drive/) *might* help.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: I've tried refid but it didn't work. It shown just logo and nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you give me some guidelines how to proceed?

I would buy a new SSD for however cheap they are now, or use some new disk on your new motherboard and do a clean install of [Debian] linux.  When that is up and running, slave your old debian disk and just copy off whatever data from it you need to.

Having linux installed on a MBR formatted disk, trying to make that work on a UEFI system that requires an EFI partition and a GPT partition table, is apples and oranges (probably worse) and I don't think would be worth the effort even trying, and i don't think it's even possible.  I think you (anyone) would be much happier with... new motherboard, new disk, clean install of linux.  Rather than making some old disk with linux try to work.

Comment: It is possible, but indeed probably not worth trying, compared to how little time it would take to re-install on a new disk!

Comment: After your comments I decided to reinstall. It was pretty fast and solved my problem